# Is it possibe to change similar libraries (Data Analysis) in Python within the same code?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, modin

I use the [modin](https://github.com/modin-project/modin) library for multiprocessing.
While the library is great for faster processing, it fails at `merge` and I would like to revert to default pandas in between the code.

I understand as per PEP 8: E402 conventions, import should be declared once and at the top of the code however my case would need otherwise.

```
import pandas as pd
import modin.pandas as mpd    
import os
import ray

ray.init()
os.environ["MODIN_ENGINE"] = "ray"

df = mpd.read_csv()
do stuff
```

Then I would like to revert to default pandas within the same code
but how would i do the below in `pandas` as there does not seem to be a clear way to switch from `pd` and `mpd` in the below lines and unfortunately modin seems to take precedence over pandas.

```
df = df.loc[:, df.columns.intersection(['col1', 'col2'])]
df = df.drop_duplicates()
df = df.sort_values(['col1', 'col2'], ascending=[True, True])
```

Is it possible?
if yes, how?

Comment: why can't you just import them both at the top with different names?

Comment: https://github.com/modin-project/modin/issues/896

Comment: Thank you. That helped. please post it as an answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since many have posted answers however in this particular case, as applicable and pointed out by @Nin17  and [this comment from Modin GitHub](https://github.com/modin-project/modin/issues/896#issuecomment-564445814), to convert from Modin to Pandas for single core processing of some of the operations like `df.merge` you can use

```
import pandas as pd
import modin.pandas as mpd    
import os
import ray
ray.init()
os.environ["MODIN_ENGINE"] = "ray"
df_modin = mpd.read_csv() #reading dataframe into Modin for parallel processing
df_pandas = df_modin._to_pandas() #converting Modin Dataframe into pandas for single core processing
```

and if you would like to [reconvert the dataframe to a modin dataframe](https://github.com/modin-project/modin/issues/896#issuecomment-779295816) for parallel processing

```
df_modin = mpd.DataFrame(df_pandas)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do the following :

```
import modin.pandas as mpd

import pandas as pd
```

This way you have both modin as well as original pandas in memory and you can efficiently switch as per your need.

Comment: I have added code to explain. How do i call pandas specifically for some functions like `drop.duplicates` and `loc` and `sort`

Comment: Thanks for updating the question, I assume you cannot switch to OG pandas in this case or vice versa. The important factor here is the module from which you read csv, from the code sample above I see that read it from mpd (modin), so all the methods and functions that are associated with that dataframe will be based on modin.

Comment: As @Nin17 pointed, you can call pandas with `df = df._to_pandas()` which changes the distribued dataframe to pandas dataframe that runs on a single core.

Comment: Oh alright. I wasn't aware of it. Thanks for updating.

Answer (score 0):

You can try pandarallel package instead of modin , It is based on similar concept : https://pypi.org/project/pandarallel/#description

Pandarallel Benchmarks : https://libraries.io/pypi/pandarallel

Comment: This is great however, I am am running windows environment and `pandarallel` works on either mac or WSL or linux.

Comment: It is python library so all it needs is python environment . Windows / Mac / Linux shouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 0):

As @Nin17 said in a comment on the question, [this comment](https://github.com/modin-project/modin/issues/896#issuecomment-564445814) from the Modin GitHub describes how to convert a Modin dataframe to pandas. Once you have a pandas dataframe, you call any pandas method on it. [This other comment](https://github.com/modin-project/modin/issues/896#issuecomment-779295816) from the same issue describes how to convert the pandas dataframe back to a Modin dataframe.